# PHP mysqli prepared statement INSERT error

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I am currently trying to set up a prepared statement to allow users to sign up for my web page. My POST information passes correctly to my submit page from my form, and I am able to successfully insert ?'s upon submission if I remove the prepared statement, but I get an error with this current code.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$uid = 'NULL';   
$fn = $_POST['fn'];
$ln = $_POST['ln'];
$u = $_POST['u'];
$p = $_POST['p'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$sx = $_POST['sx'];
$pn = $_POST['pn'];
$a = $_POST['a'];
$up = $_POST['CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'];
$c = $_POST['cn'];
$s = $_POST['s'];
$z = $_POST['z'];

require_once('../mysqli_connect.php');

$query = "INSERT INTO u (userid, fn, ln, username, p, dob, sx, pn, em, a, up) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);
if($stmt){
$stmt->bind_param('isssssssssi', $uid, $fn, $ln, $u, $p, $dob, $sx, $pn, $em, $a, $up);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

}

if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {
  $userid = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
  echo "Your user ID is ". $userid;
} else {
echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
// display error if occurs
var_dump($mysqli);

mysqli_close($mysqli);

?>
```

Here is the error code that I receive:

```
Error: INSERT INTO u (userid, fn, ln, username, p, dob, sx, pn, em, a, up) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1
```

I have tried changing versions of php, I am currently running 5.3, but when I switch to anything beyond I get an error for mysqli class. I have tried back ticking and quoting the ?'s but that does not seem to work either. I am hoping someone can expand upon what is already available regarding prepared statement, because I have searched high and low and have been unable to find what my problem stems from. So, I guess my question is, how do I correctly pass my variables via a prepared statement, and what syntax do I need to use near the ? placeholders?

Comment: Why are you executing the same query twice? `if (mysqli_query($mysqli, $query)) {` The `$stmt->execute();` is suppose to be sending that. The `query` function doesn't support placeholders.

Comment: I thought by running the if mysqli_query I was just making sure it successfully passed but, you are right it's very redundant since I can just test on the execute. Thanks, this solved mysql syntax error. How would I go about turning this into a multi query, based on checking if the state and city name exist in the table, and then inserting if they don't? I also have tables to link the user city/state, so if result did occur I would take that id and userid and insert into the link. This is wrapped in my initial POST if statement:

Comment: `$cityid= "SELECT id FROM c WHERE cn = '$c' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($cityid);
if ($result != true) {
$query.= "INSERT INTO c (cn) VALUES (?)";
if(!$stmt->bind_param('s', $cn)) {
  echo "insert error dawg".$stmt->error;
}
if(!$stmt->execute()){
  $cityid = $stmt->insert_id;
  echo "Your city ID is".$cityid;
} else {
  echo "Error: ".$stmt->error;
}
}`

Comment: Add code to your question; http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33990674/edit I don't really know what you are asking in the second part of that comment.

Comment: I guess what I am asking is should I wrap every bit of code for the insert in my if statement? Or should I do one step at a time, successfully insert user, then city, then link, then state, then link.

Comment: Your application logic will determine what checks you do and the order of each query. If a row should be unique then either check before insert, or better setup a UNIQUE index (or PRIMARY KEY) and use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. It's worth taking the time to do it right - do required validation and check and report errors.

Comment: I do one query at a time. I think it is more  matter of preference; if you do use `multiquery` and you end up open to SQL injections you could have a big issue, as user can execute any type of query.

Comment: But I can still use prepared statements with multiquery no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used prepared statements so you don't then need to also use `mysqli_query()`.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO u (userid, fn, ln, username, p, dob, sx, pn, em, a, up) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, $query);

$stmt->bind_param('isssssssssi', $uid, $fn, $ln, $u, $p, $dob, $sx, $pn, $em, $a, $up);
$stmt->execute();
$userid = $stmt->insert_id;
echo "Your user ID is ". $userid;
$stmt->close();
```